# Initial state for particles

Tags: particles

Is it possible to setup initial state for particles? I want to simulate drops on bottle, and need to be animated. If this is simple animation I would probably just render from specific frame but I need it to be from frame 1. I can not start emitting from negative frame as than particles are not colliding with collider, they only start on frame 1. But on frame 1 I need all particles to be born and none born after that ...

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can't you just set the emission to start at frame 1 and then stop at frame 1?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the start and end frames of the particles emission in particles setting tab. This can be negative frames (end must be the same or greater than start).
[image: particles before frame 0]

Comment: As I said, than particles do not collide with collider. Collider starts to affect particles starting frame 1.

Answer (score 0):

I found if I put Start and End Frame to 1 it almost gives me what I need, so I can work with this.